# iOS custom table view cell resize in edit mode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview

When editing the `UITableView` the round red button and the delete button overlaps the custom cell.

How can we resize the custom cell to leave space for the red round button and the delete button.

Comment: Are you using a subclass of UITableViewCell?

Comment: Yes, I am using a class based on UITableViewCell. I added some labels and images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code, you can perform different tasks depending on how, and what stage of editing the cell is in. I've commented the code heavily because it took me so long to figure this out on my own. (gets confusing)

```
  - (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {

        [super willTransitionToState:state];

        if (state == UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask) {

            NSLog(@"Default");
            // When the cell returns to normal (not editing)
            // Do something...

        } else if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) && (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)) {

            NSLog(@"Edit Control + Delete Button");
            // When the cell goes from Showing-the-Edit-Control (-) to Showing-the-Edit-Control (-) AND the Delete Button [Delete]
            // !!! It's important to have this BEFORE just showing the Edit Control because the edit control applies to both cases.!!!
            // Do something...

        } else if (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) {

            NSLog(@"Edit Control Only");
            // When the cell goes into edit mode and Shows-the-Edit-Control (-)
            // Do something...

        } else if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {

            NSLog(@"Swipe to Delete [Delete] button only");
            // When the user swipes a row to delete without using the edit button.
            // Do something...
        }
    }
```

You said you added custom labels and what not, and I've done the same before while using tableviews. I usually prefer to "hide" the views that are getting overlapped using an animation block like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3

                        animations:^ {
                            self.myTableCellSubview.alpha = 0.0f;
                        }
        ];
```

inside each of the if statements above, and changing the alpha from 1.0f to 0.0f depending on the state.

As for the indentation in general, in the attributes inspector, make sure "Indent While Editing" is checked, which you can also set programmatically with:

```
cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = YES;
```

If that doesn't work, you may have some quirkyness going on in your autosizing. In your storyboard, or xib, select the subview of your cell that needs to be indented and go to the Size inspector (ruler tab). If the subview needs to be indented from the left ( ---> ), make sure it's pinned to the left:

[image]

If the subview needs to be indented from the right  ( <--- ), make sure it's pinned to the right:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very nice! I used this function along with (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state and (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate  to do this. I can't see the indentation tool in the size tab. I do not know why it is not showing up I have xcode 4.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

You could override one of these methods i think and resize the custom cell.  Not sure this is exactly what you are asking based on the question though.

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
```

Comment: Can you provide a short example on how can this be done. Thanks for replying.