# Grouped UITablleview not editable cell indentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on the app which contains one of the grouped section UITableView with edit/delete functionality. Tableview is looked like this[image: Grouped UITableView]

```
-(IBAction) EditTable:(id)sender 
   {
    if (self.editing)
    {
      [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
      [libtable setEditing:NO animated:NO];
      [libtable reloadData];
          [tabledit setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    else
    {
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [libtable setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [libtable reloadData];
        [tabledit setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:     
                    (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
                   forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
          [self delete];
    }
}
```

On the very first row of each section I have disable the editing mode with this method:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath.row > 0;}
```

It is working fine but you can see in this image :

[image: TAblevie in edit mode]

The very first row of each section because of non-editable mode doesn't move to right side when I click on edit mode. I need these 0 index row also in right side on the click of edit button same like other rows. I didn't find any method to resolve this. If anyone has knowledge on this concept please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: plese check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927221/how-to-stop-cells-from-indenting-shouldindentwhileeditingrowatindexpath-has-no and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187073/ios-custom-table-view-cell-resize-in-edit-mode

Comment: i updated the code check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below

```
  - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

     if(indexPath.row == 0) //for each section of first row return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone
          return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

     return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;


  }
```

i forgot see your `-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
  //you may comment this method
 -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       return YES; //return for every cell as editable 
   }
```

if u run and in editing mode u will get like this

[image]

Comment: It does't work. I need to shift the non-editable row also with other rows.

Answer (score 1):

try to use below delegate method to decide editing style for cells

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

        if(indexPath.row ==0 ){
         return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
         }else{
           return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;

           }
    }
```

and change your method canEditRowAtIndexPath to =>

```
 -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return YES;
    }
```